# How can I capture rich text as input to a web form?

Tags: html, richtextbox

I need to have the user be able to cut-and-paste rich text into a big text box on my web page.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can install a JavaScript editor like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) to allow for rich text. This particular WYSIWYG editor has a "Paste from Word" function that helps reduce all the nasty character encoding problems you typically have when users attempt to publish Word documents on the web.

Comment: Please note that you can't do RTF paste to TinyMCE, at least on Mac (the browser is not the case)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it only by using IE/Windows/TinyMCE-like-widget set.

Here's some [information about clipboards](http://www.mail-archive.com/tutor@python.org/msg32897.html).